# is it possible to copy image from one server to another server

Tags: kubernetes

On the server A, I install many kubernetes images, because I could not access the dockerhub for some network issue. I want to copy some images from server A to server B. is it possible to copy the images smoothly? I have searched from google but did not found some useful imformation. It is better to copy the image from server A to server B batch than one by one. Now I am using containerd, not using docker.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull image from official or mirror then save it like this:

```
docker save registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6>pause.tar
```

copy the pause.tar to other sever and import it like this:

```
ctr -n=k8s.io  image import /root/pause.tar
```